# How do I add a facebook app to the "bookmarks" on the front page

Tags: facebook, bookmarks

I have created a Facebook game, which works with some Ajax Javascript and a PHP/MySQL Server with scores and all, But I can't figure out how to add it as a bookmark on the frontpage of the users of the app.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing that you need to do in order for the app to be added to the bookmarks of the user.
If the user uses the app it will be added to the bookmarks automatically, as it says in the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/#bookmarks):

> If your app has a Canvas URL set, a bookmark will appear in the left
>   column of the homepage as well as on the top right of a Canvas page
>   itself.

Comment: Are you using it often enough? The apps in the bookmarks bar are ordered by the usage.